# gdi+ GetWorldTransform() where is it in directx?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, directx, gdi+

so im arguing with my friend about `GetWorldTransform()`.  im saying that this `DEVICE->GetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &matWorld);` is the same as `GetWorldTransform()` in gdi+.
am i right or wrong? if im wrong what is it than in directx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, AFAIK GDI+ is 2D and DirectX is 3D. so they are not equal in that matter, and continuing on that, there wouldn't be a match either.

So according to me:

> am i right or wrong?

You are wrong.

> if im wrong what is it than in directx?

There is no equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah you are definitely wrong.  The GDI+ world transform is very simple and only allows transformations in 2D.  Checkout the [XFORM structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145228%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to see how different it is to a Direct 3D matrix.  Its not even homogeneous.  The 2 "may" end up going to the same hardware functionality but there is no guarantee of this.  GDI+ is quite a high level wrapper where Direct3D is much closer to the metal.  The 2 really aren't comparable.